# OR condition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, edit-form

I am using the jquery function and it is not checking two conditions at once.
I want to check for or condition.When I give only one condition in if statement it is working but after giving or it is not working.
here is my code

```
if($("input[title='Nature of the work']").val() != "Execute Business processes" || $("input[title='Nature of the work']").val() != "Deliver periodic reports")
{
$('nobr:contains("Is the work being currently done")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Is the work being currently done")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').show();
}
```

Comment: Is the field `Nature of the work` required field?

Comment: no it is not a required field in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the below code , i added the full script , try and let me know

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript&quot;"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            hideShow();
            $("input[title='Nature of the work']").change(function () {
                hideShow();
            });
        });

        function hideShow() {
            var txt = $("input[title='Nature of the work']").val();
            if ((txt != "Execute Business processes") && (txt != "Deliver periodic reports")) {
                $('nobr:contains("IIs the work being currently done")').closest('tr').hide();
                $('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('nobr:contains("Is the work being currently done")').closest('tr').show();
                $('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').show();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i will let you know soon

Comment: this worked. but i did not write the whole function just used the variable initialization to input field. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your code, hope it should work.

```
if(!($("input[title='Nature of the work']").val() == "Execute Business processes" && $("input[title='Nature of the work']").val() == "Deliver periodic reports"))
{
$('nobr:contains("Is the work being currently done")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Is the work being currently done")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("Frequency of the Deliverables")').closest('tr').show();
}
```

Explanation:
In your code, if any one of the condition is TRUE the IF statement will be executed as you have used OR operator, but in my code both the conditions will be checked as i have used AND operator.

```
if(A!=B || C!=D){
//do something
}
```

For checking both conditions,

```
if(!(A==B && C==D)){
//do something
}
```

Comment: but it is still not working for me !

Comment: Is this the one you are expecting if(A!=B && C!=D) or explain what you need in simple terms.

Comment: i have a input text field in the edit form. So if the input field is equal to Business unit or input field is equal to services i wanna show a dropdown but when i use or condition it does not work !
How do this in the code that i have given above? this is what i want : if(A!= B and A!=C){//do something}

Comment: it is working but it is showing only one of the items not both !